# add dlls as contgent to a nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-spec

I need my package to contain some dlls that should be delivered as content and copied to the output folder. The following configuration should do the trick, but when I am consuming the package I get error messages saying that MyDlls contain binary files instead of text files.

```
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="contentFiles\any\any\MyDlls\*.*" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>    
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="buildresults\netstandard2.0\*.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />
    <file src="buildresults\net462\*.*" target="contentFiles\any\any\MyDlls" />
  </files>
</package>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have the dlls contained in "buildresults\net462" to be delivered in the outputfolder. Any suggestion ?